# problems with Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a java program that will take int input as a option from the user. Based on the input the program will go to different method.But when i run code it gives the following error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at lab1.EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:25)
```

part of my code

```
        private Scanner reader;
        public static void main(String[] args){

        EchoClient c = new EchoClient();
        int option;
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("Select one of the following options:");
        System.out.println("1 - Iterative Server");
        System.out.println("2 - Concurrent Server");
        System.out.println("3 - Exit");

        option = c.reader.nextInt(); // Line No 25
        switch(option){
        case 1: 
               c.iterative();//calls the iterative method
               break;
        case 2:
               //some method
               break;
        case 3:
               System.out.println ("bye bye");
               break;
        }//end of switch()
        }//end of main()

        public void iterative(){
               String address;
               String ip="";
               try{ 
                  System.out.println ("Please enter your correct ip address");
                  BufferedReader getip= new BufferedReader (newInputStreamReader(System.in));
                  ip=getip.readLine();
                  }
               catch (IOException error){
                   System.err.println("Error occured");
                }
```

At line 25 is the line :  option = c.reader.nextInt();

Comment: kindly try formatting your source code in a better way so that people who want to help you do not end up wasting much of their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build reader according to the instance you want to scan.

In your case this should look like:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then, following your code snippet, you should set the `reader` owned by your instance of `EchoClient` to the built `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

`reader` is never initialized, so it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you create your new `EchoReader c`, it doesn't set the `reader` attribute - then when you try `c.reader`, you get `null`, leading to the NPE when calling `nextInt()`. Double-check that your `EchoReader` constructor sets the `reader` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

reader is never initialised as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

...did you define your private Scanner reader?
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);